# Why is viewContainerRef not filling up with multiple instances of components?

Tags: angular

I'm going through the documentation in Angular Fundamentals, trying to understand how `FactoryComponentResolvers` and `ViewContainerRefs` work . . . The code snippet below is from the Angular documentation. https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader.

The code cycles through the `ads` array, and continually loads new `adItems` into the child template.

My question is, why doesn't this process lead to multiple (eventually unmanageable) numbers of multiple instances of the same component being loaded? Alongside the `loadComponent()` method, shouldn't there be some kind of `unloading` or `destroying` process to prevent too many instances getting accumulated? Or does the `destroying` somehow occur behind the scenes? Or is `viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory)` smart enough to know that if it's already created a component, it will simply return a reference to that existing component rather than creating a new one? Many thanks in advance if anyone can please clarify!

```
export class AdBannerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() ads: AdItem[];
  currentAdIndex = -1;
  @ViewChild(AdDirective) adHost: AdDirective;
  interval: any;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadComponent();
    this.getAds();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  loadComponent() {
    this.currentAdIndex = (this.currentAdIndex + 1) % this.ads.length;
    let adItem = this.ads[this.currentAdIndex];

    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(adItem.component);

    let viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;
  }

  getAds() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.loadComponent();
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> let viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
>      viewContainerRef.clear()

In this part of the code,  the `loadComponent` function retrieves a reference to the adHost viewContainerRef object and gets rid of the existing content. So, to answer your question on why `viewContainerRef.createComponent` is not flooding the page with component objects is because that the `clear` function first destorys the existing component before anything new is created.